# Wie erkärt sich die irreguläre Flexion von "gehen"?

Tags: etymology, verb, dialect, irregular-verb

Das unregelmäßige Verb *"[gehen](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/gehen)"* wird im Präsens wie folgt gebeugt:

> ich gehe, du gehst, wir gehen

Nur als Partizip und als Nomen findet sich der Wortstamm *"-gang-"*:

> ich bin gegangen - der Gang, der Aus**gang**, der Vor**gang**, [...]

In vielen Dialekten wird *"gehen"* aber bevorzugt mit dem Stamm *"-gang-"* gebeugt. So findet sich im Schwäbischen folgende Flexion:

> ***Präsens:*** I gang, du gescht/goscht, mir ganget - ***Partizip:*** I bin gange

Wie ist es zu dieser seltsam unterschiedlichen Beugung gekommen? Warum gibt es den *"Gang"* im Neuhochdeutschen nur im Nomen und im Partizip?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ähnliche Unterschiede finden sich auch in anderen germanischen Sprachen und [Svenska Akademiens Ordbok](http://g3.spraakdata.gu.se/saob/show.phtml?filenr=1/91/76.html) hat eine etwas ausführlichere Erklärung der vermutlichen Etymologie. Eine mögliche Erklärung ist, dass die Formen ursprünglich auf verschiedene Wurzeln zurückzuführen sind und nicht einfach unterschiedliche Formen vom gleichen Stamm sind. Eine zweite Erklärung ist, dass "gehen" als Angleichung von "gang" durch "stehen" entstanden ist. SAOB führt als weiteres Beispiel für die Angleichung zwischen Antonymen die französischen Wörter "rendre" (aus Latein "reddere") und "prendre" (aus Latein "prendere").

Answer (score -3):

Ich meine, die Annahme, dass zwei verschiedene Ursprungswörter vorliegen könnten, ist nicht sehr überzeugend. "gehen" wird oft verkürzt ausgesprochen und wird zu "gen". Davon wäre die Stammform 3 "gegenen/gegennen". Das spricht sich nicht so gut.
Es könnte sein, dass das zu "gegannen" und "gegangen" verändert wurde.

Eine Hypothese von mir zu einer nicht sehr überzeugenden Hypothese von zwei Ursprungswörtern, bei der man aber kein zweites Ursprungswort angeben kann.